# FontWeight implementation error after flutter upgrade to 3.1.0

Tags: flutter

Missing concrete implementation of 'getter FontWeight.value'.
Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.

'''

```
enum TitleWeight implements FontWeight {
  regular(FontWeight.w400),
  medium(FontWeight.w500),
  semiBold(FontWeight.w600),
  bold(FontWeight.w700),
  extraBold(FontWeight.w800),
  black(FontWeight.w900);

  final FontWeight weight;
  const TitleWeight(this.weight);
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

This was simply solved by implementing the value Function, as such

```
/// Cinzel
enum TitleWeight implements FontWeight {
  regular(FontWeight.w400),
  medium(FontWeight.w500),
  semiBold(FontWeight.w600),
  bold(FontWeight.w700),
  extraBold(FontWeight.w800),
  black(FontWeight.w900);

  @override
  int get value => _weight.value;

  final FontWeight _weight;
  const TitleWeight(this._weight);
}
```